# D3 Choropleth Map

Tags: javascript, d3.js, choropleth

I am building a D3 US choropleth map,i need to bind data for map from asmx webservice(output given as Json).

```
        d3.queue()
        .defer(d3.json, "https://d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json")
        .(d3.json,'Geodata.asmx/GetGeodtls',
                function (error, jsondata) {
                  (unemployment.set((jsondata.map(function (d) { return d.ZIP_CODE })), +jsondata.map(function (d) { return d.TRV })));                       


                })
        .await(ready);

        function ready(error, us) {
            if (error) throw error;

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "counties")
              .selectAll("path")
              .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
              .enter().append("path")
                .attr("fill", function (d) { alert(d.TRV); return color(d.TRV = unemployment.get(d.ZIP_CODE)); })
                .attr("d", path)
              .append("title")
                .text(function (d) { return d.TRV + "%"; });

            svg.append("path")
                .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function (a, b) { return a !== b; }))
                .attr("class", "states")
                .attr("d", path);
        }
```

How to proceed, any idea ?

Then I did something like below

```
         d3.queue()
        .defer(d3.json, "https://d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json")
        .defer(d3.json, 'Geodata.asmx/GetGeodtls')
        .await(ready);

        function ready(error, us,un) {
            if (error) throw error;

            un.forEach(function (d) {
                //alert("foreach" +d.ZIP_CODE);
                unemployment.set(d.ZIP_CODE, +d.TRV);

            });

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "counties")
              .selectAll("path")
              .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
              .enter().append("path")
                .attr("fill", function (d) { return color(d.TRV = unemployment.get(d.ZIP_CODE)) ? color(d.TRV = unemployment.set(d.ZIP_CODE)) :"darkgreen"  })
                .attr("d", path)
              .append("title")
                .text(function (d) { return d.TRV + "%"; });

            svg.append("path")
                .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function (a, b) { return a !== b; }))
                .attr("class", "states")
                .attr("d", path);
```

I am getting nothing in this unemployemnt.set(d.ZIP_CODE,+d.TRV) , I just want to use ZIP_CODE and TRV as my dataset in map.

Comment: What is your actual problem? The code you provide has at least one severe error (line 3 should be `.defer(d3.json,'Geodata.asmx/GetGeodtls',`). Apart from that, are you getting any errors? What exactly does not work?

Comment: There isnt any error my webservice returns ZIP_CODE & TRV, how to pass those values in the ready function? If I pass those value in way what i have given above map is not loading.

Comment: Those geographic features are counties but your data is recorded by zip code. You need to have county ids in your data to be able to bind data to the geojson

Comment: @AndrewReid Thanks you very much!! I didn't know that!!